# Laravel - Route [service.leave_requests.allLeaves] not defined

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project I have this Controller:

```
class ServiceLeaveRequestsController extends Controller
{
  public function all_leaves()
  {  
    $userCompany    = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $allLeaves               =       HrLeaveRequest::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))->get();

        return view('service.leave_requests.all_leaves')->with('allLeaves', $allLeaves);

  }
}
```

The view blade is:

service\leave_requests\all_leaves.blade

routes\web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'service', 'as' => 'service.', 'namespace' => 'Service', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('all_leaves', 'ServiceLeaveRequestsController@all_leaves')->name('allLeaves');
});
```

When I click on this route:

```
   <span class="info-box-number"><a href="{{ route("service.leave_requests.allLeaves") }}">Click to View <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a></span>
```

I got this error:

> Route [service.leave_requests.allLeaves] not defined.

How do I get it resolved.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use This because here your name route is "allLeaves"

```
   <span class="info-box-number"><a href="{{ route("allLeaves") }}">Click to View <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a></span>
```

Comment: Error changed to Route [allLeaves] not defined when I used a href="{{ route("allLea